# xtext content assist based on previous node

Tags: xtext, content-assist

In the original grammar I have a parser rule defined as

```
Property: k=Cident '=' (simple=PropertyValue | map=MapLiteral);
```

I have two different property `A` and `B`. They have difference properties in map. 
For example:

```
typeA = {'class': 'typeA', 'upper_bound': 50};
typeB = {'class': 'typeB', 'possible_value': 'int'};
```

`typeB` won't have `upper_bound` property.

If I override `completeProperty_Map`, I could cast `model` to `Property` to check if `k` is `typeA` or `typeB`, then suggest difference auto completion. However, after first proposal, it comes to

```
typeA = {'class': 'typeA',
```

Then my auto complete won't work. It only knows it's in a map, but doesn't know this map is on the right hand side of a `Property`. Such that I can't check if `k` is `typeA` or `typeB`.

Any help?

==============================================================

Update: add more code snippet

```
PropertyValue
  : c=Constant
  | u=UnreservedKeyword
;

Constant:
  STRING_LITERAL | INTEGER | FLOAT | BOOLEAN | UUID | HEXNUMBER
;
```

==============================================================

Update: 
I found out I could get parent object in AstTree from the argument `model` and iterate through all map entries to check if `class` property has shown and the value of `Cident`. Quite dumb but works.

Comment: Could you please provide more information: How `PropertyValue` and `PropertyValue` are defined in the Grammar? Are `typeA` and `typeB` special names (string constants) known to the content assistant? Could you please provide some snippets from the content assistant, that could help to better understand your problem?

Comment: Oh, I found out I could use `model.eContainer` to get the parent node in AstTree.